# Installing CPAN module DBD::mysql on macOS Sonoma fails with "symbol not found."

Tags: perl, homebrew, dbd-mysql

I have a tool, [expandfile](https://multicians.org/thvv/htmx/expandfile.html), written in Perl, that can iterate over rows from an SQL query.

After upgrading to Sonoma, expandfile still worked, using Perl 5.30.
I dumped my MySQL database to a text file.

Then I stupidly typed "brew update ImageMagick" and lots of programs were upgraded,
including Perl and MySQL.  I am having trouble getting expandfile to access SQL.

I updated my environment vars to change PERL5LIB to refer to the new version of Perl, 5.38.2.
(I checked and $ARCHFLAGS from Ventura was still "-arch arm64" on this M2 Air.)

Homebrew installed MySQL Server version 8.3.0, so I configured MySQL, reloaded my dump, and set up '.my.cnf'.
Data came back fine, as expected... checked from the command line tool.

Then I typed "expandfile" and got the error that Perl module LWP was missing (as were all other CPAN modules).
This is what I expected: I always have to re-install CPAN modules after major macOS upgrades.
(I did 'sudo -H cpan' and got a message that I had to execute 'o conf init pushy_https', so I did, and 'o conf commit'.)
Then I did a long sequence of 'sudo -H cpanm install xxx' to reinstall about 40 CPAN modules.
(A few CPAN modules had install errors due to missing prerequisites, fixed.)

I always do DBI and DBD::mysql last, because extra configuration is needed and sometimes there are problems.
When I did "sudo -H cpanm install DBD::mysql" I got the message:

```
installing DBD::mysql failed installing DBD::mysql
DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-5.004.tar.gz : writemakefile NO '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.38.2_1/bin/perl Makefile.PL --testuser=root --testpass=xxx' returned status 512
```

I looked in .cpanm/work/number.number and found the build log for DBD::mysql.
It got as far as {:Running Makefile.PL:} and failed with
"Can't link/include C library 'zstd', 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting."
Never saw this before.

I tried setting some configure-args:
sudo cpanm --configure-args="--libs='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/lib'" install DBD::mysql

That got further, but still fails. The log has 269 warnings about macros, and then finally says "compilation failed, bailout called"

```
Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
at t/00base.t line 15.
Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
Error:  Can't load '...mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(../blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 0x0002):
symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows' at /opt/homebrew/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.38/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 210. at t/00base.t line 15.
```

I must have missed a step somewhere.. but I thought I did the same steps that worked last time.
Do I need something else in configure-args?

Comment: Why do you use sudo when installing with the homebrew cpanm?

Comment: *"I have a tool, expandfile, written in Perl, that can iterate over rows from an SQL query."* How did you install `expandfile` ?

Comment: Tested on macOS 14.2.1 M1, homebrew perl 5.38.0. First ran `brew install mysql` Then downloaded DBD::mysql from https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-5.004.tar.gz and ran
`perl Makefile.PL --libs="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/lib -lmysqlclient -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lzstd -lresolv"`. This worked also compilation with `make` worked. I did not run `make test` since I have not setup a DB test user

Comment: Mysql v8.3 is an experimental version at the moment, not recommended even for development activities!

Comment: Thanks Håkon, two responses:
I think I tried cpanm without sudo and it got an error. The root account has a symlink to my account's bash profile and variables, and this method used to work.
How I installed expandfile: it and its .pm components are in my /bin which is on my PATH... which starts with "/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/thvv/bin:"

Comment: Thanks Shadow, perhaps Homebrew installed 8.3 before it was ready. I will look for a way to revert MySQL to the previous version and see what happens.

Comment: Shadow, I checked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/faqs-general.html and it says "MySQL 8.3 and 8.0 are actively supported for production use. "

Comment: Håkon -- you did it! i copied your libs= and it worked.

Comment: @THVV Great to hear that you found a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Håkon’s comment,
I restarted, and then executed

```
sudo cpanm --configure-args="--libs='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl\@3/3.2.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/lib -lmysqlclient -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lzstd -lresolv'" install DBD::mysql
```

It succeeded.